# min_row attribute of workbook unexpectedly changes value

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I load excel workbook using `openpyxl=2.5.8`, check it's dimensions to create a numpy array of same size. I have noticed very unusual behavior, `min_row` attribute changes its value after `list(worksheet.rows)`. 
`worksheet.rows` is a generator yielding rows, this behavior only occurs after dumping generator to a list.

How is it possible that `min_row` changes?

[File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1klAH5ugx6E0lJNCT5Mm6aIZuvyvR6PSt/view?usp=sharing)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook


worksheet = load_workbook(file).worksheets[0]


worksheet.max_row # output: 14
worksheet.min_row # output: 2
worksheet.max_column # output: 20
worksheet.min_column # output: 1

list(worksheet.rows)

worksheet.max_row # output: 14
worksheet.min_row # output: 1
worksheet.max_column # output: 10
worksheet.min_column # output: 1
```

Comment: Not really possible to say without the file. All boundaries are calculated on the fiy.

Comment: I have uploaded the file and provided download link.

Comment: I can't replicate the behaviour with that file. You must be doing something else.

Comment: weird, I just downloaded file on colleague's laptop and run the snippet, reproduced results from my local machine

Comment: Well I can reproduce this behaviour on min_row (https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV8Us.png) but I do not have any direct solution - the only thing I found is that it does not affect deep copy of the workbook, so maybe you can somehow solve this by copying workbook?